# CFileDialog save file with empty name

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, cfiledialog

I have a CFileDialog and I'm trying to allow it to accept an empty value after calling the DoModal() function. I've played with the ofn flags but can't seem to get the dialog box to move forward in the process unless there is a valid entry in the save box. I don't necessarily want invalid file names allowed, I just want an empty value. I've thought about setting a default name when the dialog opens but can't find a flag/value in the OPENFILENAME struct that'll help with that.

Comment: Isn't that what the "Cancel" button is for?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the parameter in CFileDialog that takes a default filename, lpszFileName, This does the trick for setting the default save name. Going to investigate the possibility of taking an empty value still.